# Check if multiple bool variables have specific value

Tags: c#, boolean

In my current app I have 6 players and everyone has 1 boolean variable. Which under certain circumstances are set to true (originally they are false).. The problem is that I want to check which 5 variables are set to true and which one is set to false but I can't come up with any good idea.. only some if statements checking every single combination

```
if(a && b && c && d && e && !f)
{
    //f is false in this case and I will do some operations here
}
```

However this is the ugliest and not well written code ever. What would be more general way of doing it?

Comment: Could you publish the class with the boolean property inside of it + some executation code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have a hard time doing this with just booleans. But if you wrap the boolean in a class with some other data, it becomes easier.

```
class Item
{
    public bool   IsCondition {get; set;}
    public string Name        {get; set;}
}

var itemsToCheck = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item { IsCondition = true;  Name = "A",
    new Item { IsCondition = true;  Name = "B",
    new Item { IsCondition = false; Name = "C",
    new Item { IsCondition = true;  Name = "D",
}
foreach(var item in itemsToCheck)
{
    if(!Item.IsCondition)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Item {item.Name} is false"); 
    }
}
```

You can also get a list of all those that are false with Linq

```
var items = itemsToCheck.Where(i => !i.IsCondition);
```

Or if you know there will only ever be one that is false, you can get that single item.

```
var item = itemsToCheck.Where(i => !i.IsCondition).Single();
```

So there's two takeaways from this:

- You should store sets of similar data in a collection, such as a List
- Use a class when you want to group some information together.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! This will do the job, I will mark this as an answer asap.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign them boolean list and then work with them.

```
List<bool> bools = new List<bool> {a,b,c,d,e,f};

if (bools.Count(x => x) == 5) // if there are 5 true items
{
    int index = bools.IndexOf(false); // index of false item
    // do your things here.
}
```

Remember that indexes are 0 based. means that index 0 refers to first item.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd use array/list and just count `false` values:

```
var onlyOneFromListIsFalse = players.Select(p => !p.SomeProperty).Count() == 1;
```

You can use similar approach with individual variables

```
var onlyOneVariableIsFalse = ((a ? 0 : 1) + (b ? 0 : 1) ... (f ? 0 : 1)) == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) and List/Array will greatly reduce your code.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var players = new List<Player>
        {
            new Player("Orel", true),
            new Player("Zeus"),
            new Player("Hercules", true),
            new Player("Nepton"),
        };

        var playingPlayers = players.Where(p => p.IsPlaying);
        foreach (var player in playingPlayers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(player.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPlaying { get; set; }

    public Player(string name, bool isPlaying = false)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsPlaying = isPlaying;
    }
}
```